# In Jeditable, how do I make it so that when I click the div to edit, the text box content has initial value that is processed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parsing, templates

When the user clicks on the div, jeditable will make a text box.  However, I want the initial text to be done with `function stripTags()`, instead of what's on the page.

The reason is that I'm using some URL techniques to turn plain text links into URLs.  When the user clicks on the div, jeditable is turning them into `<a href=>..</a>`

Is there a "beforeSubmit" option in jeditable?

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jeditable you can pass options object parameter to the editable function. So in this option parameter specify an event that triggers starting to edit the item so you have complete control on the element before & after starting to edit.
Example:

```
$('#sampleDiv').editable(callBackFunction, {
   event: 'edit', //the event that will trigger the editing
   cssclass:'editForm' //the class of the form that will have the input textbox
   //some other options refer to Jeditable website for other options
});
```

now all you have to do is create a function that will trigger the editing and bind it to the doubleclick, click or whatever event you like I'm going to use click for this example.

```
$('#sampleDiv').click(function () {
   $('#sampleDiv').trigger('edit');
   //now the input box is appearing so you can change the value here or do whatever u want
   var input = $('.editForm input');
   input.val(stripTags(input.val()));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Jeditable has a data function which edits your editable text before form submit.

Try:

```
$('#sampleDiv').editable('blahblah...', {
  data: function(value, settings){
     return stripTags(value);
  }

});
```